# Onesignal Push Notification to specific category

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have a database of persons on my server and it contains a `group number` attribute. I want to send separate notifications for each of the group. Using the following code, it will send a notification to all apps. How do I set or subscribe the app so that it will know that a certain mobile belongs to a certain group? Each of the members needs to login first before accessing the app.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        console.log('Received Device Ready Event');
        console.log('calling setup push');
        // Set your iOS Settings
        var iosSettings = {};
        iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt"] = false;
        iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL"] = true;

        window.plugins.OneSignal
          .startInit("3074529d MY APP ID HERE d5eb61b000")
          .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
            alert("Notification received: \n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            console.log('Did I receive a notification: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
          })
          .handleNotificationOpened(function(jsonData) {
            alert("Notification opened: \n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            console.log('didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
          })
          .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert)
          .iOSSettings(iosSettings)
          .endInit();
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user subscribes to your app, you can get the OneSignal Player ID of the device and save it to your database.

Anytime after the init call use [getPermissionSubscriptionState](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-) method to get the Player ID.

Then you can follow OneSignal's [Database Integration Guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/internal-database-crm) to associate the player ID with your user's and group number.

Another option is to use OneSignal [Tagging Guide documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-tagging-guide) to associate devices with groups.